# How can I invert the mouse Y axis in Minecraft Pi

Tags: mouse, minecraft

I am trying to invert the mouse Y axis in Minecraft Pi but can't find a solution to this as there are no options available in Minecraft Pi. Would/can I write a python script that runs in the background to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Minecraft Pi Edition's Python API is rather limited. Per the documentation there are only three fields to set via `world.setting()` or `player.setting()`, and you can confirm this by running `strings minecraft-pi` and inspecting the output.

You may have considered using `xinput list` and `xinput set-prop`. Whether this works could depend on your particular mouse hardware, but from what I can tell changing the coordinate transform matrix would only affect the 2D cursor position, not mouse look (controlled instead by delta movements).

Update: There's [Phirel's patch to enable Survival Mode](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-editions/minecraft-pi-edition/1960005-survival-mode-patch). It also happens to enable basic options in the GUI, including "Invert X-axis" (confusing terminology: invert Y direction ~= flip about X axis)

You can read below for my other approach using SDL.

---

One way to effectively mod this closed-source executable is to intercept SDL function calls with your own modified SDL.

```
sudo apt install libx11-dev libxext-dev
curl -O https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15.tar.gz
tar xvf SDL-1.2.15.tar.gz
cd SDL-1.2.15
./configure
```

To invert the mouse Y, find the part of the library where it normally sends the deltaY value and invert it!

```
--- a/src/events/SDL_mouse.c
+++ b/src/events/SDL_mouse.c
@@ -185,7 +185,7 @@ printf("Mouse event didn't change state - dropped!\n");
                event.motion.x = X;
                event.motion.y = Y;
                event.motion.xrel = Xrel;
-               event.motion.yrel = Yrel;
+               event.motion.yrel = -Yrel;
                if ( (SDL_EventOK == NULL) || (*SDL_EventOK)(&event) ) {
                        posted = 1;
                        SDL_PushEvent(&event);
```

then build and inject your modified library to test:

```
make
LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/build/.libs/libSDL-1.2.so.0 minecraft-pi
```

Or if you have enabled full OpenGL with KMS, you may have to avoid the script at `/usr/bin/minecraft-pi` overriding with its own `LD_PRELOAD` setting. More complicated, but you can inject the Mesa wrapper alongside like so:

```
(cd /opt/minecraft-pi && \
 LD_PRELOAD="$(cd -)/build/.libs/libSDL-1.2.so.0 libbcm_host.so.1.0" \
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=lib/mesa \
 ./minecraft-pi)
```

One cool perk of this approach is that because mouse look uses relative movements while you're leaving the absolute Y position untouched, cursor movement still functions as before.

If you wish to make further modifications or need to debug your changes, add `printf()` statements, rebuild, and rerun.

Thanks for reading. If you reached this point, you either missed the key text above recommending a simpler approach of using the Survival Mode patch, or you're using this as a tutorial for a further input modding. If the latter, you may find some useful troubleshooting steps in [the followup question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92174/how-can-i-invert-the-mouse-y-axis-in-minecraft-pi-followup/100877).